# How to automatically create an index of child sites at the root url for a multisite installation?

Tags: multisite, google-maps

I have a Wordpress multisite with different child sites for different geographical locations. At the root url, I want to show an index page with links to the child sites.
1. How do I automatically populate links to the child sites?
2. How do I automatically populate site descriptions for the child sites?
3. How do I create a Google map with markers representing the child sites, assuming the locations of the child sites are entered in the site descriptions?

Answer (score 1):

For create the links to your child sites use this

```
    function elenco_sotto_siti(){
global $wpdb;
$blogs = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->blogs  WHERE public='1' AND archived='0' AND mature='0' AND spam='0' AND deleted='0' ORDER BY blog_id "),ARRAY_A );  
    return $blogs;

    }
```

For question 2 and 3, i use the option framework plugin, and i grab the description and other setting with

```
    switch_to_blog($site->blog_id);
$immagine= of_get_option('example_uploader');
    restore_current_blog();
```

If you create an option fot the address and grab it into your main site you can create the map
The option framework plugin is at this URL http://wptheming.com/options-framework-plugin/